# How to make border-radius work in case there is a div tag with an image

Tags: html, css

I have HTML and CSS like this:

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
  background-image: url("https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/f1502649-e034-40ab-9fed-7992b7d550c6.jpg?im_w=1200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  border-radius: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'></div>
```

When I resize the browser, the bottom border-radius doesn't work.

Comment: Actually `border-radius` works correctly, but your image is not continued till the end of div. You can use `background-size: cover;` for your item class to solve this problem.

Comment: @Vinh The Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your `background-size` to `cover` will resolve your problem. As you can see below:

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
  background-image: url("https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/f1502649-e034-40ab-9fed-7992b7d550c6.jpg?im_w=1200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `background-size: cover;` and you could add `background-position: center;` to [center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) your image.

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 768px;
  background-image: url("https://a0.muscache.com/im/pictures/f1502649-e034-40ab-9fed-7992b7d550c6.jpg?im_w=1200");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius:50px 50px;
}
```

```html
  <div class='item'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you might want to use `background-size: cover;`. It will stretch the image to cover the whole area of the div (so the `border-radius` will be visible).

However since the image can be cropped after this change (specifically in the case when it does not have the same aspect-ratio like the area of the div), it might be necessary to use also `background-position` to position the background image as you like (by default it is aligned to the top left corner).

Most probably you will have good results with centering it, but the possibilities are endless ;)

```
background-size: cover;    
background-position: center;
```